# How to use/deploy a Keras/Tensorflow model without full tensorflow package?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deployment, architecture, keras

I am using Keras (with tensorflow backend) to build a neural network model. The model is saved in model.h5 file.

Now deployment, the model is going to run in thousands of small instances, each with limited resources. So I don't want to install the entire tensorflow package in the deploy environment because it takes too much resources.

I am wondering if I can just copy some files from the tensorflow package, use them to do the model scoring? Or if it is possible to export the network weights and architecture from the model.h5? That way I can just write a small scoring function using the weights.

Or is there any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You may be interested in [TFLite](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/tflite/), meant for applications which require binaries with lower footprints.

Comment: Perhaps [tensorflow-serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/setup)?